# PouchDB-find with multi-layer document

Tags: pouchdb

I have asked the following question on the CouchDB Github Repo, where it was suggested to me to ask it here on Stackoverflow instead.

Suppose we have a couchdb document structured like this:

```
{
  "_id": "4234",
  "properties": {
      "active": "true",
  }
}
```

I have managed to use createIndex and find to access the `_id` field, which is quite trivial based on the [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html).

But how would I go about querying for example the property `active`?
I unfortunately haven't found info about this on the web.

Help is appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force way is to create an index for `properties`

```js
index: {
   fields: ['properties']
}
```

And to query with respect to `properties.active`

```json
{
   selector: {
      properties: {
         $eq: {
            active: "true"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However that's not so great! `properties` may add a bunch of information not needed in the index, and in turn potentially create a bloated, wasteful index.

A better solution is to target specific properties of `properties`, e.g. `properties.active`:

```js
{
  index: {
    fields: ['properties.active']
  }
}
```

And for example this query to find all `properties.active` = "true"

```json
{
   selector: {
      "properties.active": {
         $eq: "true"
      }
}
```

It's important to understand that when querying nested fields one must wrap the index field specified as a string e.g. `"properties.active":`.  That one point stumbles some people.

The snippet below demonstrates the approach.

```js
// canned test documents
const getDocsToInstall = () => {
  return [{
      "_id": "4234",
      "properties": {
        "active": "true",
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "4235",
      "properties": {
        "active": "true",
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "4236",
      "properties": {
        "active": "false",
      }
    }
  ]
}

let db;
const gel = (id) => document.getElementById(id);

const initDb = async() => {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
  return db.createIndex({
    index: {
      fields: ['properties.active']
    }
  });
}

const setJsonToText = (id, json) => {
  gel(id).innerText = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 3);
}

(async() => {
  await initDb();
  const query = {
    selector: {
      "properties.active": {
        $eq: "true"
      }
    }
  };
  const results = await db.find(query);
  setJsonToText("query", query);
  setJsonToText("results", results);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.find.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  <pre>Query</pre>
</h3>
<pre id="query"></pre>
<hr/>
<h3>
  <pre>Results</pre>
</h3>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```